# How do I automate copying data from one worksheet in Excel and append it to an existing table in another worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have two sheets of data.  The first sheet is imported data that will show total users to my site from the day before.  The second sheet is a table with all historical data from those daily reports.  I'd like to automate a way to copy the data from my first sheet (that data will always be in the same cell) to a new row at the bottom of my existing table. Here's what I have:

```
Sub Insert_New_Rows()
    Dim Lr As Integer

    Lr = Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Rows(Lr + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Cells(Lr + 1, "AF") = Cells(Lr, "AF") + 1
    Sheets("Day Before").Range("$A$12:$B$12").Copy
    Sheets("Historical").Cells(Lr + 1, "AF").Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

In this, you'll see that my table is in columns AF and AG. When I run this macro, it only adds a row, it does not copy and paste the information.

Comment: See how you did `Sheets("Historical")` before `cells`? Do that with _all_ `ranges/cells/range objects`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure where your table starts on the sheet "Day Before". So, I am assuming that it starts in row 1. Based on this assumption here is a little revision to your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Insert_New_Rows()

Dim lngNextEmptyRow As Long
Dim lngLastImportRow As Long
Dim shtYstrdy As Worksheet
Set shtYstrdy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Day Before")

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Historical")
    lngNextEmptyRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Rows(lngNextEmptyRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    .Cells(lngNextEmptyRow, "AF").Value2 = _
        .Cells(lngNextEmptyRow - 1, "AF").Value2 + 1
    lngLastImportRow = shtYstrdy.Cells(shtYstrdy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    shtYstrdy.Range("A1:B" & lngLastImportRow).Copy _
        Destination:=.Cells(lngNextEmptyRow, "AF")
End With

End Sub
```

Changes:

1. Explicit coding as suggested by @findwindow stating the workbook and the sheet **before** each `Range`, `Cells`, reference.
2. Copy and paste in one line of code (before three lines of code).
3. Using `lngNextEmptyRow` instead of `LastRow` so be can skip all these `+1`.
4. Determine the size (last row) of the table on the sheet "Day Before", so we know how much we need to copy over.

I hope this is the answer you've been looking for. Let me know if I misunderstood something or if anything requires more explanations.

Comment: This worked! Thank you :) I deleted the lngLastImportRow part because yesterday's data will always be in the same cell.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to Active or Select Ranges.  It is best to work with the Ranges directly.  Rarely should you use ActiveCell, ActiveWorkSheet, or Selection.

### This is how Copy and Paste work

Here is the shorthand for Copy and Paste

> Range(SourceRange).Copy Range(DestinationRange)

Know that this will work for you:

> Sheets("Day Before").Range("$A$12:$B$12").Copy Sheets("Historical").Cells(Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp).Offset(1)